# Null object reference toolbar android

Tags: java, android, object, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a second `Toolbar`, next to the one I have in my top bar.
Basically there is a `Button` and when this is pressed, a bar pops up in the window.
The user should be able to read something on the bar and can push a `Button`.
Right now I am trying to just get text on there. But that doesn't seem to work.

.java function: (called when some button is pushed, this shows the toolbar)

```
public void showDialogue() {
    //Set popupscherm as view
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupscherm,null);
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(GraphActivity.this);
    adb.setView(v);
    // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("test"); //Here it gives the error
    AlertDialog alert = adb.create();

    alert.show();
```

popupscherm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </LinearLayout>
```

error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
 View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupscherm,null);
 toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

instead of

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

because `view v`  has the `popupscher.xml` view otherwise with this `findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` you are trying to find the toolbar in the current set layout of activity which is different from `popupscherm.xml`

Comment: Oh my god................. Thanks!

Comment: @aze45sq6d  welcome dude :p

Comment: Nono, thanks so much. I looked for this for 2 hours and it's so simple.

Comment: @aze45sq6d just kidding  :P and now you know and that's how we all learn many things :) , happy coding

Comment: Great it's worked for me, thanks :)